# Customers from same city and postal code using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have table customers . I want all customer data where there are more than one matches for postal_code and city. So that they will concentrate more on that area ( business requirement)

customers:

```
cust_id    city    postal_code   
1001       ABCD     M123            
1002       ABCD     M124  
1003       ABCD     M123
1004       BBCD     M001
1005       BBCD     M001
1006       BBCD     M002
```

from that customers table (I have huge no.of recors in that) I want to get the result like

```
   cust_id    city    postal_code   
    1001       ABCD     M123            
    1003       ABCD     M123
    1004       BBCD     M001
    1005       BBCD     M001
```

how to achive this in mysql please help me. thanks.

Comment: What is your criteria?

Comment: What the logic of result?

Comment: how do u want to filter data?

Comment: @sergio Yes, wondering that.

Comment: he may want to use group by

Comment: I am going to guess you want all rows where there is more than one matches for `postal_code`.

Comment: select cust_id, city, postal_code from customers c where (select count(cust_id) from customers where city=c.city and postal_code=c.postal_code) > 1

Comment: I thing that now we are thinking instead of OP)

Comment: Downvoted for reasons stated in first couple of comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW DUPLICATED_CUST as SELECT city, postal_code from customers 
GROUP BY city, postal_code 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

SELECT cust_id, c.city as city , c.postal_code as code from customers c, DUPLICATED_CUST d
where c.city=d.city and c.postal_code=d.postal_code
```

Comment: thanks this is working for me exactly the way I wants.